# Get url file from S3 Laravel show allowed memory exhausted

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

i'm little bit confused. I just want to show url file that will linked, but when show URL file, its show this error

```
[2021-02-17 09:21:25] production.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 7440695296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 42654830216 bytes) {"userId":317,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0): Allowed memory size of 7440695296 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 42654830216 bytes) at /var/www/lspphc/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php:307)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}
```

The code i use like this ( in blade )

```
Storage::url($document->document_url)
```

with `$document->document_url` value is path to the file in s3

Comment: If you disable this line of code, are you getting this exception?

Comment: Nope, for temporary , i replace the storage facade with direct url from bucket, and its work fine

Comment: Look into file streaming, otherwise it looks like you are losing the file in memory and trying to serve it that way.

Comment: Yeah i confused too, why this getting this error. All file is exist, and still just wonndering why get url file make this exception